# @remote annotation in Scala type mismatch

Tags: java, scala, rmi

My trait:

```
@remote trait Computer {
  def execute(task: Task[Any]): Any
}
```

Snippet of main class in a companion object of a class `ComputerImpl` that implements `Computer` simply by defining `execute` to be `= task.execute()`.

```
val name = "Computer"
val engine: Computer = new ComputerImpl()
val stub = UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(engine, 0).asInstanceOf[Computer]
```

I get this error:

```
system/ComputerImpl.scala:19: error: type mismatch;
 found   : api.Computer
 required: java.rmi.Remote
      val stub = UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(engine, 0).asInstanceOf[Computer]
```

It goes away if I do the more explicit `trait Computer extends Remote` but in "Scala for Impatient" it says "Scala uses annotations `@cloneable` and `@remote` instead of the `Cloneable` and `java.rmi.Remote` interfaces for cloneable and remote object."

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks as if it should work, but this is a compilation phase problem. The compiler is applying the `@remote`, that is adding in the interface to the trait definition, after it's done the type checking for the compilation. However, the following works:

```
val stub = UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(engine.asInstanceOf[java.rmi.Remote], 0).asInstanceOf[Computer]
```

but it's a bit ugly.

EDIT: It's failing in the `typer` compilation phase, whereas it looks like the `@remote` substitution is being done in the `jvm` phase, which is after the `typer` phase.

And in fact, this is a known issue, [type inference fails with @remote annotation](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-150). From there, Martin Odersky says:

> That's completely as speced. @remote is not the same as `extends
>   Remote' for the type checker.

There is no further explanation, but I wouldn't hold your breath for a compiler solution :-)

Comment: Hm, what circumstances would one use the `@remote` annotation then?